# Unable to delete S3 bucket using "aws-sdk" in typeScript/node.js

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am tying to delete `s3` bucket by using `aws-sdk` but keep getting `Error: BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.` error.

My bucket is clear and what I understood is somehow I am not able to delete versioning. I tried `s3.listObjects` and `s3.listObjectVersions` but no luck. What am I missing here?

***Code:***

**Option-1:** Using `s3.listObjects`

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const region = "region";
const bucketName = "bucketName";
const secretAccessKey = "secretAccessKey";
const sessionToken = "sessionToken";
const accessKeyId = "accessKeyId";

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
  region: region,
  sessionToken: sessionToken
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

const finalResult = emptyS3Directory(bucketName);
async function emptyS3Directory(bucketName: string) {
    let currentData;
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName
    };

    return await s3
      .listObjects(params)
      .promise()
      .then(async (data) => {
        if (data.Contents.length > 0) {
          currentData = data;

          const deleteParams = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Delete: { Objects: [] }
          };

          currentData.Contents.forEach(({ Key }) => {
            deleteParams.Delete.Objects.push({ Key });
          });

          // await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams).promise();
          await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams, function(error, deleteObjectsData){
            if(error) {
              console.log(`deleteObjectsData -> Error: ${error}`);
            } else {
              console.log(`deleteObjectsData -> Data: ${deleteObjectsData}`
              );
            }
          })
        }
        return await s3.deleteBucket(params, function(error, deleteBucketData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(`deleteBucketData -> Error: ${error}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`deleteBucketData -> Data: ${deleteBucketData}`
            );
          }
        });
      })
      .then(async () => {
        // If the bucket contains many objects, the listObjects() call
        // might not return all of the objects in the first listing. Check to
        // see whether the listing was truncated. If so, retrieve the next page of objects
        // and delete them.
        if (currentData && currentData.IsTruncated) {
          await this.emptyS3Directory(params.Bucket);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`Error from emptyS3Directory: ${error}`);
        throw new Error("There was an issue retrieving the Bucket");
      });
  }
```

**Option-2:** Using `s3.listObjectVersions`

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const region = "region";
const bucketName = "bucketName";
const secretAccessKey = "secretAccessKey";
const sessionToken = "sessionToken";
const accessKeyId = "accessKeyId";

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: secretAccessKey,
  region: region,
  sessionToken: sessionToken
});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

const finalResult = emptyS3Directory(bucketName);

async function emptyS3Directory(bucketName: string) {
  let currentData;
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName
  };

  return await s3
    .listObjectVersions(params)
    .promise()
    .then(async data => {
      if (data && data.Versions.length > 0) {
        currentData = data.Versions;
        // console.log(`data.Versions -> ${currentData}`);
      }

      if (data && data.DeleteMarkers.length > 0) {
        currentData = data.DeleteMarkers;
        // console.log(`data.DeleteMarkers -> ${JSON.stringify(currentData)}`);
      }

      const deleteParams = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Delete: { Objects: [] }
      };

      currentData.forEach(({ Key, VersionId }) => {
        deleteParams.Delete.Objects.push({ Key, VersionId });
      });

    //   console.log(`deleteParams.Delete.Objects -> ${JSON.stringify(deleteParams.Delete.Objects) }`);
      await s3.deleteObjects(deleteParams, function(error, deleteObjectsData) {
          if(error) {
              console.log(`deleteObjects -> Error: ${error}`);
          }
          else {
              console.log(`deleteObjects -> deleteObjectsData: ${deleteObjectsData}`);
          }
      })

      await s3.deleteBucket(params, function(error, deleteBucketData) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(`deleteBucketData -> Error: ${error}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`deleteBucketData -> deleteObjectsData: ${deleteBucketData}`
            );
          }
      });
    })
    .then(async() => {
        if(currentData && currentData.IsTruncated) {
            console.log(`currentData.IsTruncated -> ${currentData.IsTruncated}`)
            await this.emptyS3Directory(bucketName);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Try adding to the params object `force_destroy: true`,

Comment: @SándorBakos for `option-1` or `option-2`?

Comment: I would try both, I just assume that is the problem